# What does IPv4 Connectivity = Not Connected mean in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

What does IPv4 Connectivity = Not Connected mean in network connection properties in Windows (Windows 8 Professional)?

How this state can be achieved?

I need answers on exact questions if possible please.

[image]

Comment: Means you have no internet

Answer (score 0):

> What does IPv4 Connectivity = Not Connected mean in network connection
>   properties in Windows (Windows 8 Professional)?

This will say "Not Connected", "Limited Access", "Local Only", or "Internet Access" according to what Windows' Network Location Awareness features have found out about your connection when it was initialized.

> How this state can be achieved?

"Not Connected" would mean that DHCP didn't work, APIPA didn't work, and/or Nlasvc could not make a connection to the Microsoft NCSI server to verify external connectivity.

(I'm going to try to find some definitive documentation on this if possible to verify this.)

Comment: How to stop APIPA and/or Nlasvc on the machine to achieve the state?